# Can't install Kali Linux from USB, fails to find CD-ROM drive

Tags: linux, boot, usb, installation

I successfully made a live USB of the Kali Linux.

When I boot from the USB it gives an option to install. I clicked on that option. At one point it was detecting and mounting CD-ROM drives. As I have no CD-drive or any ROM-drive on my laptop, it gives an error

> Can't mount and detect CD-ROM drives.

I tried the "live something" option that takes me directly to Kali Linux and it loads successfully but I can't install it permanently. I want to install it so I won't have to waste my time plugging and unplugging the USB.

How to get past the CD-ROM detection and make the installation finish correctly?

Comment: 1. How did you create USB installation? I did it using program unetbootin many times and never had any problems. It works with Kali 2.0 without any problems. 2. Did you try to use expert install option? Usually in expert install mode you can skip certain steps by moving to next one in the menu/installation agenda.

Comment: i did it with rufus there is no probem in making usb but it gives that error

Comment: See the point no 2 in my previous comment. Kali is based on Debian so it has the same installer. Try to use expert install and skip CDROM step.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. It says "You have failed to insert a Debian instalation medium" as if it is trying to detect the USB as a CD-ROM. However, I can Live boot no problem, just can't install.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could resolve the error by repeating the steps :

Run the installer.

Open a shell (<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>).

Create the directory cdrom directly on the root of the file system:

> mkdir /cdrom

Note : **If you got problems making the directory /cdrom, disable the CD-rom player in BIOS or disconnect the cable**

Mount the USB as if it is a CD-ROM:

> mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom

Where sdb1 is your USB device.

You could carry on installation now

After executing `mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom`, `cd` into the /cdrom directory and do an `ls` to see if the files are there. Then press <kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to go back, continue and re-select "detect CDROM"

Source :[ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127398/usb-drive-install-of-ubuntu-12-04-server-fails-cant-find-components-from-cd-r) and [debian](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=48602)

Another [layman solution](http://techsharez.com/cd-rom-couldnt-be-mounted-kali-linux-error-solved/) was :

> when the Window shows  CDROM couldn't be mounted ,
>
> 1. Unplug your USB from system and re insert it
> 2. wait for mount/ detection (usb LED glow)
> 3. Hit Continue

You could do what I did. Hit escape, type install, hit enter, skip CD drive.

Comment: @UsmanZiaMalik updated answer buddy give it a try

Comment: Not working for me. I need to do `mount /dev/sdb1 /cdrom -o ro` or the system will yield `/dev/sdb1 is already mounted on /lib/live/mount/medium`. Anyway, even when all the files are on `/cdrom` the installer keeps asking for `Retry Y/N` .

Comment: Layman solution works

Comment: Unplugging the usb and putting it back in worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: after executing `mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom` `cd` into the `/cdrom` directory and do a `ls` to see if the files are there. Then press `ALT-F1` to go back, continue and reselect "detect CDROM"

Comment: For those where this doesn't work: go to "Execute Shell" if trying to run Kali linux and type in `dmesg`.  You may be getting errors but it's a start to debugging why no one's solution will work.  In my case, it may actually be a kernel bug, or I've put the wrong installation on.  I'm not sure, as it takes forever to download the distro from their site but hey, it may just be that.

Comment: NOTE: If you are using YUMI multiboot, you'll need to bind the OS directory, not just the contents of the stick.

Comment: It is not about mouting. If I run the shell, all the files are already in /cdrom It complains about a cdrom drive.

Comment: please at first see what is your usbdrive name is 
it was not /dev/sdb1 on my pc..
so check it first.

Comment: Doesn't work...

Comment: I had same issue while I was installing Kali 2018 from USB that was built by using  "WinSetupFromUSB-1-8" on Window 10 to install multiple OS like Ubuntu, Win7, WIn8, Win10 & Kali from same USB as Bootable USB. I was trying to install Kali as dual boot system. Same issue I was facing then I just open the CD-ROM drive (Eject the CD-ROM) and let it be open until installation is not finish. Then remove USB and mount in Another USB PORT. Sudden it's detected USB and CD ROM both and installation is continue as it should be. Now UBUNTU & Kali both working fine :)

Comment: I had to run `mount /dev/sdb1 /cdrom` without the parameter, as I was getting "illegal argument", but your solution worked

Comment: In my case using the GUI installer it was ALT+CTRL+F2 for the console and ALT+CTRL+F5 to return.

Comment: layman solution of remove/reinsert usb  works for me too.

Comment: What if I have no installation media but instead just extracted the `.iso` file in a partition using 7zip?

Answer (score 47):

If you use Rufus (v 2.x) to burn the ISO to USB drive, make sure the option is "**DD Image**" in "*Create a bootable disk using*". Not sure if Unetbootin offers the same option. If image is copied using this method, you don't need to go to terminal and manually mount it.

With Rufus (v 3.x), you can not explicitly choose DD mode. IF the ISO is hybrid or has DD mode, Rufus will prompt you to choose ISO or DD mode AFTER clicking start button.

Answer (score 11):

I tried all the answers here and more google results, but none worked. I eventually figured it out, the issue is the file format is not vfat, but iso9660.

When you get the CDROM not found error follow these steps:

Enter a shell (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>)

*Note: Kali told me to press (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>), but this didn't work*

Get a list of devices with **blkid**:

```
~ # blkid
/dev/sdc1: UUID="2018-04-12-12-04-16-00" LABEL="Kali Live" TYPE="iso9660" PARTUUID="81c5e086-01"
```

*Note: I have shortened my list to the relevant row. Also you can see the storage type is iso9660, not vfat*

Mount the Kali CD with the mount command:

```
~ # mount -t iso9660 /dev/sdc1 /cdrom
```

Check the contents of /cdrom are as expected:

```
~ # ls /cdrom
autorun.inf     efi             g2ldr.mbr       md5sum.txt      win32-loader.ini
boot            efi.img         install         pool
debian          firmware        isolinux        setup.exe
dists           g2ldr           live            tools
```

Switch back to the installer (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>)

*Note: Kali told me to press (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>), but this didn't work. I tried <kbd>F1</kbd> through to <kbd>F5</kbd> until I found the correct combination*

From the menu tell it to mount the CDROM, if asked choose /dev/sdc1 and /cdrom. I know we have already mounted the drive, but for some reason this step didn't work previously, but worked fine after following the previous steps.

The install will now continue as normal.

Comment: This solution works for me, thanks! My environment is Kali 2018.3/Rufus 3/DD Image.

Answer (score 2):

checked the issue myself right now: it's a WAY MORE simple - use "Graphical install". It seems to rise additional hw-related services and it works just fine! Also - if you're using 2 flash drives - plug OFF the drive you're about to install it **to**, boot it in GUI - and then plug the target drive.

Comment: Don't think that's the solution. I have the CD-ROM issue and I only use the Graphical Install option.

Comment: The DD Image option above worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried every single answer but none of them worked.
After some more searching online I found an answer that worked for me.

It is fairly simple but just download Win32 Disk Imager.
Click on the folder icon and change the filter to all files or *.*
Then select your .ISO file, select your device and click on write.

After doing this I inserted my USB (3.0) into a USB 2.0 port on my computer.
When I booted to my USB it worked instantly.

Comment: This worked, also after trying everything else! I think it's because the system originaly was  a windows machine, then dual booted to Ubuntu. This method was the only one that allowed me to load the ISO to drive "F", which allowed the windows boot loader to see it? IDk, It worked.

Answer (score 1):

From any flavor of Ubuntu, you need to use the application [Startup Disk Creator](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#2) in order to make the live USB Kali, and successfully install Kali from live USB. Because, some others tools to make bootable USB stick from ISO, results to fail install Kali from live USB, as [MultibootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/).