# Install Kali Linux 2016.2

Tags: windows-8

Hey I'm new to computer programming in general and I've been trying for a few hours to install Kali Linux 2016.2. I get to the the point where I have to detect the CD or DVD and with my ASUS Q200E laptop which is about 4 years old.

The laptop is small therefore it doesn't have a CD or DVD reader. Moreover instead of BIOS it has UEFI and I've tried for a while going off [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/962926/cant-install-kali-linux-from-usb-fails-to-find-cd-rom-drive) but I cannot for the life of me install Kali Linux

If anyone could help I'd appreciate it greatly. Also I've completed the Linux live USB steps by using Universal USB Installer-1.9.6.8 if that helps. I've also tried taking it out and inserting it again when it says

> There was a problem reading datat from the CD-ROM. Please make sure it is in the drive. If retrying does not work, you should check the integrity of your CD-ROM.

Comment: in what century that you still install using the CD or DVD drive? And why do you keep editing again and again and add some bit of nonsense? Are you afraid of periods and paragraphs? I'm sure no one will read that mess

Comment: I'm not using the CD/DVD driver I'm using a USB.

Comment: This is not a FAQ, please have a [tour](http://superuser.com/tour) first. And format your code again. I'm not doing that twice for you.

Comment: If you're going to learn, you might want to learn with a 'regular' distro, and a VM host first. Dualbooting is risky if you don't know what you're doing, and kali is a special purpose distro

Comment: I'm not fresh off the boat I'm just new as in installing linux with dualbooting thanks for the advice though, I'm gonna stick with the dualboot

Comment: I tried a second usb using another program, turned out it didnmf have the MD5 checksum

Comment: Christ now its saying it can't install GRUB

Answer (score 0):

I decided to give up on dualbooting so I just downlaod the amd64 torrent of it and then used the live version from tha amd64