# Kali Linux Installation error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, compact-disc

I've some problems installing Kali Linux on my computer.

- The first error message is the following:

> An installation stem failed. You can try to run the failing item again from the menu, or skip it and choose something else. The failing step is: Detect and mount cd-rom

- Fortunately, I was able to find a fix for this using the following command

  mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom
- The problem I'm facing now is with the next step. The error message is the following:

> There was a problem reading data from the cd-rom. Please make sure it is in the drive. If retrying does not work, you should check the integrity of your cd-rom.

- I checked the integrity of my cd-rom and here's the message I got:

> The cd-rom you have inserted is not a valid Debian CD-ROM. Please change the disk

I have no idea on how to proceed. Any clue?

Comment: Please see this: https://superuser.com/questions/962926/cant-install-kali-linux-from-usb-fails-to-find-cd-rom-drive/1151202#1151202

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with the CD you are using. It should have been mounted automatically. This may be because you copied files to the CD instead of burning an image, or because you wrote the image to a partition of a USB stick instead of to the drive.

If you are finding this process difficult, you should probably not be installing Kali Linux. To quote their documentation ["Should I Use Kali Linux?"](https://docs.kali.org/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux) --

> Kali is a Linux distribution specifically geared towards professional penetration testers and security specialists, and given its unique nature, it is NOT a recommended distribution if you’re unfamiliar with Linux or are looking for a general-purpose Linux desktop distribution for development, web design, gaming, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution bro...

mkdir /media/usb
mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/usb
mount --bind /media/usb/multiboot/kali-linux-2016.2-amd64 /cdrom

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you explain this solution of yours? Which step in the question is it addressing? You can [edit] your answer to included this information :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Rufus to burn the iso in the usb drive, be shure to burn as dd and not as iso! is very important
Good Luck