# Installing Kali Linux, stuck at "Detect and mount CD-Rom"

Tags: kali-linux

I am currently trying to install Kali Linux on my Laptop (the image was written in DD mode) using the Graphical interface and I get stuck at "Detect and mount CD-ROM" but it doesn't give me the error "Can't mount and detect CD-ROM drives."

I trying the solution given by BlueBerry - Vignesh4303 for this question [Can't install Kali Linux from USB, fails to find CD-ROM drive](https://superuser.com/questions/962926/cant-install-kali-linux-from-usb-fails-to-find-cd-rom-drive?newreg=95a19df34306431aac41773a0d4c2edc):

> Unplug your USB from system and re insert it
>
> wait for mount/ detection (usb LED glow)
>
> Hit Continue

I unplugged the usb key, got "Installation step failed", waited 30 sec., plugged the usb, pressed *continue* and I get a black screen.

Next, I entered

> `mkdir /cdrom`

in the command prompt but the directory was already made. Then I trying mounting the CD-Rom with

> `mount -t vfat /dev/sdb1 /cdrom`

(replacing "sdb1" with the proper name for my usb device) and it said that the resources for this device was already used.

I then tried the boot option "Live (amd64)" and it failed to boot giving the error message "Can not mount /dev/loop0 (/run/live/medium/live/filesystem.squashfs) on /run/live/rootfs/filesystem.squashfs."

Also, I did verify the SHA-256 Checksum of the ISO file.

Moreover, I tried the boot option "Live (amd64)" on a different laptop and the OS started without any problem. Therefore, the issue is not the USB key.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with a Debian installer, and found this to be an issue with USB support.

It seems that the Linux installer can't handle "XHCI" USB controllers (i.e. when it boots from them, it can't "detect" it as a CDROM).

If you go into BIOS, disable the XHCI USB controller, but enable the enable the USB2.0 EHCI controller, the installer seems to be able to "see" that as a CDROM, and is able to proceed.

Of course, the steps to perform the above will vary depending on the motherboard, but below are the steps for how I got it working on an AMIBios minipc:

BIOS (via pressing Del at boot screen) > Chipset menu > southbridge option > usb configuration > disable XHCI mode > enable USB2.0 EHCI Support > Usb RMH Mode enabled* > Usb EHCI debug* disabled > USB per port control* disabled > all ports are enabled* > save and exit.

- means that was the default setting.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a bootable flash using Rufus, probably the best. When doing it select 'create using dd image' it should work just fine

Comment: I did use Rufus to create the bootable usb and as I mentioned in the first sentence I also did create it using DD mode (I tried both modes).

Answer (score -1):

i went to my BIOS and diabled all my drives but the sata and usb then when it wants to detect the cd drive i unplugged the usb and plugged it back in then clicked continue one of the first easy problems ive had.